# What will be the best regex Expression for censoring email?

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

Hello I am stuck on a problem for censoring email in a specific format, but I am not getting how to do that, please help me!

Email : `exampleEmail@example.com`

Required : `e***********@e******.com`

Help me getting this in javascript,
Current code I am using to censor :

```js
const email = exampleEmail@example.com;
const regex = /(?<!^).(?!$)/g;
const censoredEmail = email.replace(regex, '*');
```

Output: `e**********************m`

Please help me getting `e***********@e******.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
const email = 'exampleEmail@example.com';
const regex = /(^.|@[^@](?=[^@]*$)|\.[^.]+$)|./g;
const censoredEmail = email.replace(regex, (x, y) => y || '*');
console.log(censoredEmail );
// => e***********@e******.com
```

*Details*:

- `(` - start of Group 1:

  - `^.|` - start of string and any one char, or
  - `@[^@](?=[^@]*$)|` - a `@` and any one char other than `@` that are followed with any chars other than `@` till end of string, or
  - `\.[^.]+$` - a `.` and then any one or more chars other than `.` till end of string
- `)` - end of group
- `|` - or
- `.` - any one char.

The `(x, y) => y || '*'` replacement means the matches are replaced with Group 1 value if it matched (participated in the match) or with `*`.

Answer (score 1):

If there should be a single @ present in the string, you can capture all the parts of the string and do the replacement on the specific groups.

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\s@])` Capture the first char other than a whitespace char or @ that should be unmodified
- `([^\s@]*)` Capture optional repetitions of the same
- `@` Match literally
- `([^\s@])` Capture the first char other than a whitespace char or @ after it that should be unmodified
- `([^\s@]*)` Capture optional repetitions of the same
- `(\.[^\s.@]+)` Capture a dot and 1+ other chars than a dot, @ or whitespace char that should be unmodified
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FmYPvv/1)

In the replacement use all 5 capture groups, where you replace group 2 and 4 with `*`.

```js
const regex = /^([^\s@])([^\s@]*)@([^\s@])([^\s@]*)(\.[^\s.@]+)$/;
[
  "exampleEmail@example.com",
  "test"
].forEach(email =>
  console.log(
    email.replace(regex, (_, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5) =>
      `${g1}${"*".repeat(g2.length)}@${g3}${"*".repeat(g4.length)}${g5}`)
  )
);
```